# emacs how to define hotkey C-u to Delete from current position to the beginning of line

Tags: emacs, registerhotkey

I hava know C-u 0 C-k could do that thing, but I really want use C-u delete from current position to the beginning of line just like the bash readline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you really don't want to do that -- trust me. `C-u` is far too important in Emacs to be used for something else. And to substitute a different key for what `C-u` does would be a pain and troublesome for you in the end, IMHO.

Instead, find some other key that you're comfortable with and assign that to a command that does what you want. For example, rebind a key that is already bound to a command that you don't really care about (e.g. `M-k`).

For example:

```
(defun kill-to-bol ()
  "Kill text from point to beginning of line."
  (interactive)
  (kill-region (point) (line-beginning-position)))

(global-set-key "\M-k" 'kill-to-bol)
```

Comment: I concur on this one, although I have `C-u` bound to `undo`. I've rebound it long ago,
thinking that I wouldn't need `universal-argument`. Now I need it, but I can't bind it to
`C-u`, since it's muscle memory by now. It's now on `;-u` instead.

Comment: thank you for your help and advice, but just like @abo-abo said I think I don't need universal-argument and I really want use the same hotkey in bash and emacs, so I insist use C-u.  Maybe i will bind universal-argumant to another key when I find I need it.

Comment: Just make sure that you don't run out of single-chord shortcuts
by the time you actually need `universal-argument`. It *must* be on a single-chord.

Comment: @XiaorongLiao: I'll bet you a TangBao and some PiJu that you will find you need/want `universal-argument`... It's one of the wonders of Emacs, especially if you write your own commands --- you get multiple behaviors with the same basic key sequence.

Comment: @Drew: haha, I just see this, are you saying chinese(Tangbao and Piju 汤包和啤酒)? And I have bound universal-argument to A-u. really appreciate your help :)

Comment: @XiaorongLiao: Yes, but I cannot read Chinese characters. I just know how to say a few words, so I can fake the PinYin for them. Cheers!